# Service Broker - Measure how long do messages persist in sys.transmission_queue

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

is there anyway I can measure how long messages are remaining in sys.transmission_queue for e.g  an average figure for a given period ?

Comment: The `enqueue_time` isn't doing it for you?

Comment: that only gives me time it was added to to the queue if Im lucky enough to catch it in there, I need to report accurately for say an hour how much traffic the queue has and the avg time a message spends there

Comment: You might be able to cobble something together by querying the performance counters related to SB; try `select * from sys.dm_os_performance_counters where object_name like '%broker statistics%'`. There are no ready-to-go counters for the average time, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Extended events to the rescue! First, define the following session:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [broker_transmission_queue] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.broker_dialog_transmission_queue_dequeue,
ADD EVENT sqlserver.broker_dialog_transmission_queue_enqueue
ADD TARGET package0.ring_buffer
GO
```

Let that run for a while as your service broker workload is running. Then, run the following query:

```
WITH e AS (
    SELECT e.query('.') AS event
    FROM (
        select CAST(dxst.target_data AS XML) AS target_data
        FROM sys.dm_xe_session_targets AS dxst
        JOIN sys.dm_xe_sessions AS dxs
            ON dxst.event_session_address = dxs.address
        WHERE dxs.name = 'broker_transmission_queue'
            AND dxst.target_name = 'ring_buffer'
    ) AS t
    CROSS APPLY t.target_data.nodes('/RingBufferTarget/event') AS tgt(e)
), parsed AS (
    SELECT event.value('(event/data[@name="dialog_id"])[1]', 'uniqueidentifier') AS dialog_id, 
    event.value('(event/data[@name="message_sequence_number"])[1]', 'bigint') AS message_sequence_number,
    event.value('(event/@timestamp)[1]', 'datetime2') AS timestamp,
    event.value('(event/@name)[1]', 'sysname') AS event_name
    FROM e
)
SELECT b.timestamp, e.timestamp, DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, b.timestamp, e.timestamp )
FROM parsed AS b
JOIN parsed AS e
    ON e.dialog_id = b.dialog_id
    AND e.message_sequence_number = b.message_sequence_number
    AND b.event_name = 'broker_dialog_transmission_queue_enqueue'
    AND e.event_name = 'broker_dialog_transmission_queue_dequeue'
```

Essentially, we're matching (conversation_handle, sequence_number) tuples between the enqueue and dequeue events. Once you've that that matching, you can do whatever math you want (counts, averages, etc).